# Using optional chaining in typescript when using the find by key bracket syntax

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am attempting to use the optional chaining operator on the following:

```
productPrice1: product.prices["1"]?.amount.amount_1,
```

The question mark that I have in place ensures that if a child object of key ["1"] doesn't exist it will not fail. However, I would like to do the same if the prices object (the parent object) doesn't exist as well.

prices is an object with child objects that have keys such as "1", "2", "3". I want to first check if prices is null, if not then check if ["1"] exists.

My initial attempt was to try this and it isn't working:

```
productPrice1: product.prices?["1"]?.amount.amount_1,
```

I am trying to avoid doing the following and wondering if it is my only option:

```
productPrice1: product.prices != null ? product.prices?["1"]?.amount.amount_1 : null,
```

Answer (score 17):

Assuming your `product` value is of something like the following type:

```
declare const product: {
    prices?: Partial<Record<"1" | "2" | "3",
        {
            amount: {
                amount_1: number
            }
        }>>
}
```

Then you can use [optional chaining](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) like this:

```
const val = {
    productPrice1: product.prices?.["1"]?.amount.amount_1
}
```

The important piece to note here is that the syntax for optional chaining is *always* `?.` with the dot, *even when you aren't using dotted property access*.    According to [the tc39 optional chaining proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining/blob/master/README.md#syntax) (emphasis added):

> The Optional Chaining operator is spelled `?.`. It may appear in three positions:
>
> `obj?.prop       // optional static property access
>   obj?.[expr]     // optional dynamic property access
>   func?.(...args) // optional function or method call`

Yes, it's weird, and they know it.  According to the proposal's [FAQ](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining/blob/master/README.md#faq):

> #### `obj?.[expr]` and `func?.(arg)` look ugly. Why not use `obj?[expr]` and `func?(arg)` as does <language X>?
>
> We don’t use the `obj?[expr]` and `func?(arg)` syntax, because of the difficulty for the parser to efficiently distinguish those forms from the conditional operator, e.g., `obj?[expr].filter(fun):0` and `func?(x - 2) + 3 :1`.
>
> Alternative syntaxes for those two cases each have their own flaws; and deciding which one looks the least bad is mostly a question of personal taste. Here is how we made our choice:
>
> - pick the best syntax for the `obj?.prop` case, which is expected to occur most often;
> - extend the use of the recognisable `?.` sequence of characters to other cases: `obj?.[expr]`, `func?.(arg)`.
>
> As for <language X>, it has different syntactical constraints than JavaScript because of <some construct not supported by X or working differently in X>.
>
> #### Ok, but I really think that <alternative syntax> is better.
>
> Various alternative syntaxes has been explored and extensively discussed in the past. None of them gained consensus. Search for issues with label “alternative syntax”, as well as issues with label “alternative syntax and semantics” for those that had impact on semantics.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gBxk4ArmBgFzwDeAsAFDx04wCWYIaA-GQAqwaNQQAeAErgkMYAIBEARknwAPvEkAmOYskBmSQBoa9fRT0HjUALZICKUodrG7dMxasB9aWRQFTAIxAwj9ugBffwNAgD4wmmDqGmR0LAAPeABeG31cfCIMTiYWNwZM4gA6XGZWNiKAbRlJAF0Kx0sMIsaXaSj4IA)